# Stack several time the same channel?

Tags: bezier-curves, dopesheet, graph-editor

I have a complex animation movement so I parented my mesh to several empties that I animate separately.

**EDIT** : eg. a robot character, made of serval meshes; *which are parented to :*

1. a null who rotates on the Y axis (main move); *which is parented to :*
2. a "ticking" cycle on the Y axis; to break the "linearity" of the rotation with a stopmo-like movement.  The tick is only a few keys with a cycle modifier applied on the curve.

I personnaly think that it's more easy to "break" the animation steps.

I was wondering if, rather than doing this (can be a mess for complex animations), it was possible to stack several time the same channel (here, Y rotation) so I can combine those two movements while keeping my keys clean ?
If it is possible, how ?
Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking ('over-animate'?). Are you able to add more detail to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using **drivers**, you can use a channel as input value for almost everything you want to animate.

To keep it simple, I've used only two objects: the location X channel of the Sphere will be applied to the location X channel of the Cube

[image]

In this example, I've added drivers to the Cube location, (move the cursor over the location fields then press <kbd>d</kbd>)

In the Graph Editor, switch to Drivers Mode

[image]

Select the channel you want to animate, then set the Drivers properties in the Properties Panel (<kbd>n</kbd>)

If you only need to copy the channel without any operations, you can set type="Averaged Value".
Otherwise, you can choose the type you need:

[image]

Comment: That a nice way to do it.  I was wondering about anything a little easier to use, but that is fore sure a way to achieve it.  Thanks !